# Word wrap with continuous dot(.) using css

Tags: css, word-wrap

I am trying to do wordwrap with any kind of characters using `css`.

Here is the `css` what i am using

```
.wordbreak {
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /*Chrome & Safari */ 
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Somehow word wrap doesn't work with continuous dot(.), see this codepen [link](https://codepen.io/nikhilexe/pen/QZMjOB)

In this example you see a lot of dots without any whitespace characters in between. They do not break at the window's edge hence leading to a horizontal scrollbar. After that is a looooong word without any whitespace characters in between and this breaks at the edge of the window as expected.

Why don't the dots break at the window's edge?
Can I solve this in CSS alone?
Is there a workaround, maybe in JavaScript?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by ' wordwrap with continuous dot(.) ' . And if you want a solution with only CSS why do you tag javaScript ?

Comment: @MihaiT I edited the question. It should be clearer now

Comment: not only with (.) dot it won't work with any special charecters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `word-break: break-all;` form your CSS it will work as expected. You want to break word and you cannot use `break-all` and `break word` at the same time

#### Explanation

> word-wrap: break-word recently changed to overflow-wrap: break-word
>
> will wrap long words onto the next line.adjusts different words so that they do no
>   t break in the middle.
>
> word-break: break-all
>
> irrespective of whether it’s a continuous word or many words, breaks
>   them up at the edge of the width limit. (i.e. even within the
>   characters of the same word)
>
> So if you have many fixed-size spans which get content dynamically,
>   you might just prefer using word-wrap: break-word, as that way only
>   the continuous words are broken in between, and in case it’s a
>   sentence comprising many words, the spaces are adjusted to get intact
>   words (no break within a word).

Reference: [Find this link description](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/76906/what-s-the-differences-between-word-wrap-and-word-break)

```css
.wordbreak {
  
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /*Chrome & Safari */ 
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 /* word-break: break-all;  */
word-wrap: break-word;     /* Internet 
  Explorer 5.5+ */

white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id='content1'>
  <div class="wordbreak">.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................</div>
  
  <div class="wordbreak">////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////</div>
  
  <div class="wordbreak">hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello</div>
</div>

<div class="wordbreak">Hello its very  very very very very very very very  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very veryvery  very very very very very very long text</div>
```

Comment: Do you know why this is so? Maybe you hava some reference, where we can read the cause for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative up-to-date answer :
*(no need for `word-wrap`, `word-break`, nor `overflow-wrap`)*

```css
line-break: anywhere;
```

If you want your spaces to wrap too, you can also add :

```css
white-space: break-spaces;
```